# How to set arrayform in Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using Ionic for my new app.
I give users the option to store a form locally (localstorage), but when the page loads, it has to load the local form.

I tried setting it directly to the variable but that doesn't work

```js
storeLocal() {
  window.localStorage.setItem('form' + this.date, JSON.stringify(this.projects)
}

loadLocal() {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('form' + this.date)) {
    this.projects = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('form' + this.date))

    // OR...
    this.urenForm.setControl('projects', this._formBuilder.array(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('form' + this.date))));

  }
}
```

The project array has to be set with the array I stored in localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
  loadLocal() {
    const formNameStorage = "form" + this.date;
    if (window.localStorage.getItem(formNameStorage)) {
      const formData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(formNameStorage));
      this.urenForm.patchValue(formData);
    }
  }

  saveToStorage() {
    const formNameStorage = "form" + this.date;
    localStorage.setItem(
      formNameStorage,
      JSON.stringify(this.urenForm.getRawValue())
    );
  }
```

Comment: I get the following error:
Cannot assign to 'projects' because it is a read-only property.

Comment: try with "const formData"  instead of this.projects

Answer (score 0):

`setValue`, `patchValue` or `reset` are the functions you should look for, if `this.urenForm` is instance of `FormArray` class.
Also, you can try storing stringified result of `getRawValue` in localstorage and then loading it into the form using `setValue` or `reset`.

See docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray